# I recently found a switch outside a storage closet in my garage. No light fixture in that closet. How do I trace that switch?

Tags: wiring

How do I trace a light switch to it's target?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you (e.g. what type of walls do you have, where are you located, etc). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Is there power to one side of the switch? Remove the cover and observe whether there are even wires connected to the switch. If there are wires connected, then use a non-contact voltage tester to see if one is always hot. You may have to pull the switch out to see if wires are connected on the back.

Comment: If you find that it is powered, you could check in the panel for a breaker that shuts it off.  The line hot going to this switch may come down from the attic through a hole in the top plate or it may come laterally through walls via holes in the studs. Lateral wires are usually located at a standard height of 2' to 3' above the floor.

Comment: Does this closet have a wall receptacle inside? You could go up into the attic and see if there is an electrical box above the ceiling. It could be facing up or down onto the drywall ceiling. Look for coiled wires not connected to anything which may or may not be terminated in a box.

Comment: Just a hunch, attic or crawlspace light?